# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Docker container with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker-compose

Hi I am facing an issue with docker and laravel when I am trying to access to the db its said <kbd>"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory "</kbd>  So Here if my docker-composer file:

```
# Use root/root user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:
  be:
    #command: sh -c "a2enmod rewrite"
    build:
      context: ./core
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile-Backend
    ports:
      - 8887:80
    volumes:
      - ./core:/var/www/html

  fe:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Frontend
    ports:
      - 8800:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

And here if the .env file

```
APP_NAME=App
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kscbMxWntc3kCHEgsa47ra0W+eUQexPJLlZieu2j+7U=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8800/
WORKPLACE_URL=http://localhost:8800/
APP_ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8800/ # root domain without sub domain
APP_ZONE=local # local, staging, live
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock


DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN=DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN
DIGITALOCEAN_IP=DIGITALOCEAN_IP
DIGITALOCEAN_DOMAIN=DIGITALOCEAN_DOMAIN

CENSORED_DOMAINS=admin,staging,dev

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=db_password

DB_LMS_CONNECTION=mysql_lms
DB_LMS_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_LMS_PORT=3306
DB_LMS_DATABASE=db_name
DB_LMS_USERNAME=root
DB_LMS_PASSWORD=db_password

DB_SHOP_CONNECTION=mysql_shop
DB_SHOP_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_SHOP_PORT=3306
DB_SHOP_DATABASE=db_name
DB_SHOP_USERNAME=root
DB_SHOP_PASSWORD=db_password



BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync


REDIS_HOST=host.docker.internal
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL=
```

Anyone have an idea? I sue mac book pro 2022. And i sue vue as front-end. I tried some workaround from this forum. I but that wasn't work.

Comment: Where is your MySQL service in this? I can see just the backend and the frontend containers only.

Comment: Yeah, where is the `database container`  with port `3306` for example?

Comment: I use mysql service which is running in local machine.